# build mvn project with unique java.security file

Tags: java, maven, build

Does anyone know of a way to pass in the path to the "java.security" file as a paramater for maven to use during the build/installation/and test of the project? I have attempted:

```
mvn clean install -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security={path to the java.security file}.
```

and

```
mvn clean install -Djava.security={path to the java.security file}
```

I am attempting to do this because the project I am want to build requires a unique java.security file compared to the rest of the projects.

UPDATE:

I have also tried:

```
mvn clean install -Djava.security.properties={path to new java.security file}
```

and made sure that security.overridePropertiesFile=true

Comment: What happened when you did this? Did you get an error?

Comment: no error message, simply continued to use the default java.security file

Comment: Do you want the security file to be applied to the build? If so, why? Wouldn't it be enough to apply them for the tests?

Comment: When you run tests, did you configure Maven to spawn a new VM? What's your `forkMode`?

Comment: currently forkMode is set to the default, I believe I have found a solution that works though.

    mvn clean install -DargLine="-Djava.security.properties==*"

Seems to have the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the security file for tests, then you should configure `maven-surefire-plugin` correctly.

It should look like this:

```
<configuration>
    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
    <systemProperties>
        <java.security>{path to the java.security file}</java.security>
    </systemProperties>
</configuration>
```

Without this, Maven might (or might not) start a new Java VM but it won't pass its command line arguments to it.

The other alternative is to set `forkMode` to `never` and make Maven itself use a security manager. The disadvantage of this approach is that you must configure the SM to allow everything that Maven needs to do plus what your tests need.